# Check if time (startdate & enddate) cuts a time period

Tags: java, time, period

How can I check if a given startdate & enddate cuts a specific time period (train time).

I did following:

```
if ((startdate >= train.getStartDate()) &&
 (enddate <= train.getEndDate())) {
   // doSomething();
}
```

`doSomething()` get only executed, when the time is exact between the given time period. But I want also that `doSomething()` get executed, when the times are overlapped.

For example:

- Startdate: 14.10.2015 15.00
- Enddate: 16.10.2015 17.00
- Timeperiod: 15.10.2015 10.00 - 19.10.2015 10.00

In this case its overlapping and I want that `doSomething()` get executed. Any solutions?

Comment: `java.util.Date` has `.before` and `.after`, `DateTime` has `.isBefore` and `.isAfter`, and they both have a concept for equality

Comment: In my case i only have the times as long value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with long-values, I would do the following

```
if (!((train.getEndDate() < startdate) || (train.getStartDate() > enddate))) {...}
```

Alternatively, you might want to convert your `long`-vales to `java.util.Date` (`new Date(long value)`) so that you can use the Date-class.

There is also the very nice [Joda time 2.2 API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) which has an `Interval`-class that provides the following function

```
overlap(ReadableInterval interval)
      Gets the overlap between this interval and another interval.
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, this saved my day. When I have more time, im gonna try Joda time.

Comment: Sorry, but I noticed that the if conditions doesnt work proper, could you please check if ur condition have any mistake?

Comment: Can you give an example for which the condition does not work?

Comment: When startdate & enddate is before the timeperiod, then it's executing, but It should not.

Comment: I also noticed that you have some bracket mistake.

Comment: Works now. Shoud be : if (!((train.getEndDate() < startdate) || (train.getStartDate() > enddate)))

Answer (score 0):

Date has `after` and `before` methods

```
    if (yourDate.after(startDate) && yourDate.before(endDate)) {
        //doSomething
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Guava Ranges too. Here is an example:

```
public class RangesTest {

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm");

@Test
public void testDateRange() throws ParseException {
    Range<Date> timePeriod = createClosedDateRange("15.10.2015 10.00","19.10.2015 10.00");

    assertTrue(timePeriod.isConnected(createClosedDateRange("14.10.2015 15.00", "16.10.2015 17.00")));
    assertTrue(timePeriod.isConnected(createClosedDateRange("14.10.2015 15.00", "20.10.2015 17.00")));
    assertFalse(timePeriod.isConnected(createClosedDateRange("14.10.2015 15.00", "15.10.2015 09.59")));
    assertFalse(timePeriod.isConnected(createClosedDateRange("20.10.2015 17.01", "21.10.2015 17.00")));
}

private Range<Date> createClosedDateRange(String startDate, String endDate) throws ParseException {
    Date startdate= sdf.parse(startDate);
    Date enddate = sdf.parse(endDate);
    return Range.closed(startdate, enddate);
}
```

}